# Jquery event quits firing after 3 hits

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working with a small mvc view and I want to be able to toggle the data source(ajax call to controller) between either 1 of 2 locations or both.  It all works great, until I've clicked the toggles 3 different times, then all three toggles become unresponsive.  I've tried click and change events, same results.

The only other items are on the page is a left navigation view that still works after the toggles go idle.

If I navigate away from the view with the toggles and then back to it they remain broken.  If I hard refresh the page they work for another 3 clicks.

I'm at a loss on this and need some help.  Any thoughts?

my toggles

```
<div class="btn-group"id="divToggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn blue">
                <input type="radio" value="1"  class="toggle DashToggle"> US06
            </label>
            <label class="btn blue active">
                <input type="radio" value="0"  class="toggle DashToggle"> BOTH
            </label>
            <label class="btn blue">
                <input type="radio" value="2" class="toggle DashToggle"> US05
            </label>

        </div>
```

And my view consist of 5 div blocks like the following

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="dashboard-stat blue-soft">
                    <div class="visual">
                        <i class="fa fa-car"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="details">
                        <div class="number stat_ActiveJits">
                            1349
                        </div>
                        <div class="desc">
                            Active JITS
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="more" href="javascript:;">
                        View Details <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I have tried all of the following examples for the Jquery side and they all quit working after 3 clicks...

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $('#divToggle input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        BuildDashBoard(this.value)
    });    
});

$('#divToggle input[type=radio]').live().change(function () {
    BuildDashBoard(this.value)
});

$('.divToggle').on('change', '.DashToggle', (function () {
    BuildDashBoard(this.value)
}));
```

And yes the toggle classes were changed to match these.

```
$(".US06_DashToggle").change(function () {
    BuildDashBoard(1)
})
$(".US05_DashToggle").change(function () {
    BuildDashBoard(2)
})
$(".DYNA_DashToggle").change(function () {
    BuildDashBoard(0)
})
```

And finally my ajax call which works fine.

```
function BuildDashBoard(plantid)
{
    var uri = 'http://' + host + '/DashBoard/DashStats';


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: uri,
        data: { PlantId: plantid },
        success: function (d) {

            $('.stat_ActiveJits').text(d.ActiveJits.toString());
            $('.stat_PastDueJits').text(d.PastDueJits.toString());
            $('.stat_ActiveExpedites').text(d.ActiveExpedites.toString());
            $('.stat_PastDueExpedites').text(d.PastDueExpedites.toString());
            $('.stat_ActiveProductionOrders').text(d.ActiveProductionOrders.toString());
            //$.notific8('Application Options Updated', { theme: 'teal', life: 2000, verticalEdge: 'right', horizontalEdge: 'bottom' });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: The one thing in common that all of these things have is `BuildDashBoard(somevalue)`. Have you tested to see if that is being executed on the 4th iteration and on? I can confirm that your event binding does in fact result in an event handler that can trigger more than 3 times, so the problem must be `BuildDashBoard`.

Comment: I can toss a break point on the call to the function and it will hit the first 3 times only.  The cursor is never getting to the function call on any click/change after the 3rd one.

Comment: That suggests something is unbinding the event or replacing the input. (nothing in the code you provided would do that.)

Comment: I removed the navigation population from the layout file and removed the references to all JS not required for this page, same results.  It doesn't matter if I click the same toggle 3 times or 3 different ones.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that i can't recreate your problem using your code. the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: uhm... your radio buttons. they only change when you tick them from unticked to ticked, but you can't untick them with a second click, because they're radio button, not checkboxes, the only way to untick one would be to select another, and since there isn't another to select, that isn't possible... **you didn't include the fact that clicking the same one twice doesn't work on second click.** shouldn't your radio buttons either have names, or be checkboxes? http://jsfiddle.net/kcew4n0u/

Comment: I stated that wrong, i had changed them to buttons earlier as a test and received the same results.  That's when I was doing the same click 3 times.  I'm going to write my own CSS for it and see what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Well after a couple hours of fighting with this a comment Kevin B made about the radio buttons needing names made me rethink my css.  My css was not correctly doing the grouping so once i clicked a button, it was checked and never unchecked.  The reason it did not work as buttons, I have no clue and I'm done messing with it.